# ASP.Net Grid view only showing 1 result when SQL shows 34 rows

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, gridview

I have a grid view that populates from a stored proceedure via a database connection.

I pass 5 values (values from a Text Box on user input.) to the proc via a call database command. I know for a fact what I'm passing through should display 34 rows however the grid view only displays 1?

I have another asp.net application which seem to work fine and cannot see where i have gone wrong.

C#

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="Small" Width="50%" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Results" HeaderText="Results" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-CssClass="checkIt" SortExpression="Results" HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" />
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Address_Check" runat="server" ItemStyle-Width="75px" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Silver" ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:GridView>
```

CALLDATABASE

```
public static List<Data_Checker_WebformResult> CheckAdd(string Postcode, int Number, string Building_Name, string Add1, string BusinessName, string Town)
{
    using (var ctx = new DataAppDBDataContext())
    {
        return ctx.Data_Checker_Webform( Postcode,  Number,  Building_Name,  Add1,  BusinessName,  Town).ToList();
    }

}
```

please note that the proc excepts NULL values depending on combinations of text boxes being filled in.

ON BUTTONCLICK

```
protected void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkADD = Calldatabase.CheckAdd(Txt_Postcode.Text, Convert.ToInt32((Txt_Building_Number.Text.Length == 0) ? null : Txt_Building_Number.Text), ((Txt_Building_Name.Text.Length == 0) ? null : Txt_Building_Name.Text), ((Txt_Address.Text.Length == 0) ? null : Txt_Address.Text), ((Txt_Business_Name.Text.Length == 0) ? null : Txt_Business_Name.Text), ((Txt_Town.Text.Length == 0) ? null : Txt_Town.Text));
    //(Convert.ToInt32(Txt_Building_Number.Text)), Txt_Building_Name.Text, Txt_Address.Text, Txt_Business_Name.Text, Txt_Town.Text);


    GridView1.DataSource = checkADD;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

This seems to run with no errors or exception just not displaying all the results that i know are there.

Comment: Your data access code is abstracted so we can't really tell what is happening. Can you run a sql profile trace to see what sql is actually hitting the database?

Comment: I cant i'm not over sure how to do that tbh. is there anything else i could provide?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on this line `GridView1.DataSource = checkADD;` and add a watch (or just inspect) `checkADD`. Does it have 34 rows like you expect?

Comment: No it only has the 1. i have checked the proc and i see 34 however only seems to be passing 1.

Comment: I have hard coded all the variables into the proc and i can now call all 34 results. it seems to lie with me converting the blank text boxes to a null value to the proc